# How to rerun a task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, illegalstateexception

I have a task running and if it fails I want to run it again up to three times. The issue is that Android gets mad that I'm trying to run a task inside of it's self. What's the best way to get around this?

The code (look inside `task.callback` at the bottom):

```
final GenericAsyncTask task = new GenericAsyncTask();

        task.background = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(GCMIntentService.this.host);
                String addremove = "add";
                if(register == false) addremove = "remove";

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmd", addremove));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subscription_key", SUBSCRIPTION_KEY)); // unique per app
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", str));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("os_family", "android"));
                    if(addremove.equals("remove")) nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hard", "" + hard));
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);
                    Log.i(LCHApplication.TAG, "Name Value Pairs: " + nameValuePairs.toString());

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    task.result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        task.callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.i(LCHApplication.TAG, "registration response: " + task.result.toString());
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    if(attempts++ < ATTEMPTS_LIMIT) {
                        // try to register the device again
                        task.execute();
                    } else {
                        Crashlytics.logException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        task.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the retry in the actual task, don't re-run it.  If you need to re-run a task then do it via a 3rd party.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue is that Android gets mad that I'm trying to run a task inside of it's self

Beyond that, an `AsyncTask` is a single-use object. You cannot re-`execute()` an `AsyncTask` instance.

> What's the best way to get around this?

Create a new instance of your `AsyncTask`. For example, you might implement a copy constructor that you can use to make a new instance cloned from a previously-executed instance.

Or, do not use `AsyncTask`.

How well any of this will work with whatever `GenericAsyncTask` is, I cannot say, as there is no `GenericAsyncTask` in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I would suggest in this case is adopting a Handler where each time you catch an exception you would post a message for execution (up to 3 times).I find it more flexible approach specifically when you need to run frequently certain tasks.

```
 private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

           if(msg.what == YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE){
            try {
                Log.i(LCHApplication.TAG, "registration response: " + task.result.toString());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                if(attempts++ < ATTEMPTS_LIMIT) {
                    // try to register the device again
                    handler.sendEmptyMsg(YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE);
                } else {
                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                }
            }
        }    
     }

};
```

Finally you would have to associate it with a background HandlerThread.